# Question on congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove if $n|m$ where $n$ and $m$ are integers greater than $1$ and $a ≡ b ($ mod $ m)$ then $a ≡ b($ mod $n)$

Comment: It basically is since $n|m$ and by definition $m|(a-b)$ it must follow that $n|(a-b)$.

Comment: ok thanks this helped..just needed a start..

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** $a\equiv b\pmod m\iff m|(a-b)$